# Creating multiple rows in vba if multiples values are in single cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data where multiples values are in single cell, i have to arrange all values separately. could you please help me out. Your suggestion is highly appreciated.

i am not able to attach FILE..[image]

```
Countries   Cobination  Products    Q1 QUANTITY Q2 QUANTITY Q3 QUANTITY Q4 QUANTITY
USA First   Machine 90  340 600 900
Canada / USA / CHINA    First   Computer , Vehicles , Households    80  112 112 34
BRAZIL , CHINA , SA     BOOKS   10  600 0   698
CANADA  Second  BOTTLES / CARPET    4000    3243        4449
```

Result is like below

```
Countries       Products    Q1 QUANTITY Q2 QUANTITY Q3 QUANTITY Q4 QUANTITY
USA First   Machine 90  340 600 900
Canada  First   Computer    80  112 112 34
USA First   Computer    80  112 112 34
CHINA   First   Computer    80  112 112 34
Canada  First   Vehicles    80  112 112 34
USA First   Vehicles    80  112 112 34
CHINA   First   Vehicles    80  112 112 34
Canada  First   Households  80  112 112 34
USA First   Households  80  112 112 34
CHINA   First   Households  80  112 112 34
BRAZIL      BOOKS   10  600 0   698
CHINA       BOOKS   10  600 0   698
SA      BOOKS   10  600 0   698
CANADA  Second  BOTTLES 4000    3243        4449
CANADA  Second  CARPET  4000    3243        4449
```

Comment: You need to use the Convert Text to Columns wizard and/or the find/left/right functions. Use the macro recorder. You can enter the commands manually in to Excel and then look at the VB code generated for you.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Have used Text 2 Column also used Split but everything got jumbled.

Answer (score 0):

Check with this, this may not be the optimal solution. I have used 3 procedures.

1. Cell3_Count(): To know the number of rows to be inserted from the combination of strings in both the cell1 and cell3.
2. split_cell3() : To split the cell values based on the delimiter.
3. ArrangeBasedOnValues(): Has both 1. and 2. functionalities for cell1 and the output.

Please check for different cases, and make necessary changes if needed.

Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public sht1 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, k As Long, l As Long
Public str1 As String, str2() As String, str3() As String, str4 As String, s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, s4 As String
Public cnt1 As String, cnt2 As Integer, ncells As Integer

Sub ArrangeBasedOnValues()

```
Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Starting row
i = 6
```

next_cell:

```
lastrow1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Do While (i <= lastrow1)

    str1 = sht1.Cells(i, 1).Value

    str4 = sht1.Cells(i, 3).Value

    s1 = "/"

    s2 = ","

    cnt1 = 0

    'Check number of strings in cell1
    If InStr(1, str1, s1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        s4 = s1

        'count of special characters in cell1
        cnt1 = Len(str1) - Len(Replace(str1, s1, ""))

        Call Cell3_Count

    ElseIf InStr(1, str1, s2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        s4 = s2

        cnt1 = Len(str1) - Len(Replace(str1, s2, ""))

        Call Cell3_Count

    Else

        Call Cell3_Count

    End If

    'combination of elements in cell1 and cell3
    'cnt1+1 : Total numbers of strings = total number of spl chars + 1
    ncells = ((cnt1 + 1) * (cnt2 + 1)) - 1

    'Only one string in cell1
    If ncells = 1 Then

        'Add extra rows based on the combination
        sht1.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + ncells).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        sht1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = sht1.Cells(i, 1).Value

        sht1.Range("B" & i + 1).Value = Trim(sht1.Range("B" & i).Value)

        sht1.Range("D" & i & ":" & "G" & i).Copy sht1.Range("D" & i + 1 & ":" & "G" & i + 1)

        Call split_cell3

    'more than one string
    ElseIf ncells > 1 Then

        sht1.Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + ncells).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        Dim q As Integer

        q = i

        str2 = Split(str1, s4)

        For k = LBound(str2) To UBound(str2)

            'UBound(str2) + 1 : number of times each string in cell4 needs to be printed

            For l = q To i + ncells Step UBound(str2) + 1

                sht1.Cells(l, 1).Value = Trim(str2(k))

                sht1.Range("B" & l).Value = Trim(sht1.Range("B" & i).Value)

                'cnt2=0 : only one string in cell3
                If cnt2 = 0 Then

                    sht1.Range("C" & i & ":" & "G" & i).Copy sht1.Range("C" & l & ":" & "G" & l)

                'More than one string in cell3
                Else

                    sht1.Range("D" & i & ":" & "G" & i).Copy sht1.Range("D" & l & ":" & "G" & l)

                End If

            Next l

            q = q + 1

        Next k

        'cnt2>0 : need to split strings in cell3
        If cnt2 > 0 Then

            Call split_cell3

        End If

        i = i + ncells + 1

        GoTo next_cell

    'Only one string in both cell1 and cell3
    Else

        i = i + 1

        GoTo next_cell

    End If

    i = i + ncells + 1

    lastrow1 = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Loop
```

End Sub
'Number of strings in cell3
Sub Cell3_Count()

```
cnt2 = 0

'Check number of values
If InStr(1, str4, s1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    s3 = s1

    'count of special characters in cell3
    cnt2 = Len(str4) - Len(Replace(str4, s1, ""))

ElseIf InStr(1, str4, s2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

    s3 = s2

    cnt2 = Len(str4) - Len(Replace(str4, s2, ""))

End If
```

End Sub

'Split the string in cell3 based on the delimter obtained in cell3_count
Sub split_cell3()

```
str3() = Split(str4, s3)

Dim m As Integer, n As Integer

m = i

'Debug.Print cnt1 + 1

For n = LBound(str3) To UBound(str3)

    For l = m To m + cnt1

        sht1.Range("C" & l).Value = Trim(str3(n))

    Next l

    m = m + cnt1 + 1

Next n
```

End Sub